# jQuery refresh if PHP file echo's 'true'

Tags: jquery

I want my page to check if a PHP file returns 'true' every few seconds, and refresh a certain div if the PHP file has returned 'true'. Currently I have this, which isn't working and is for the complete page instead of the div (I'd like the div to refresh only instead of the complete page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval("checkTime()", 10000);
    function checkTime(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'checktime.php',
            success: function(refresh){
                if(refresh == "true"){
                    location.reload(true);
                }   
            }
        });
    }

});
</script>
```

EDIT:

Following the instructions given here I placed the following code in my header:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){        
    function checkTime(){
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'checktime.php',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.refresh == "true"){
                    $('#tv').load('tv.php');
                }   
            }
        });
    }
    setInterval(function() {checkTime()}, 10000);
});
```

My TV div looks like this:

```
<div id="tv">
<? include 'tv.php' ?>
</div>
```

When I manually go to checktime.php and refresh my index, the tv div is updated properly at the correct time. However nothing seems to happen from the javascript in the header.

Comment: What does it mean "div refresh" ?!

Comment: Yeah is there some new data that you want to put in the div when you get a response of "true"?
Also you have to make sure the server is returning the right kind of data with your $.ajax call because if not you will get the data wrapped in some html tags (even if you didn't put them there).

Comment: setInterval("checkTime()", 10000); should be setInterval(checkTime, 10000);

Comment: does id=tv exist in main page? If not jQuery doesn't know where to put it

Comment: Yeah it exists. Could it be because the content that's supposed to be refreshed is called with PHP? Would it work if I loaded the tv.php file with HTML instead?

Comment: code should work...you need to use a browser console to look at the request, and look for any errors. Also path may be different for include than from main page??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a url to send the div html when it needs the refresh. Following will load contsent from that url into the div you specify. I added a trim to the refresh text in case server sends and extraneous spaces or line breaks

Uses jQuery AJAX shortcut method load()

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval("checkTime()", 10000);
    function checkTime(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'checktime.php',
            success: function(refresh){
                if($.trim(refresh) == "true"){
                    $('#myDivID').load(refreshDivUrl)
                }   
            }
        });
    }

});
```

EDIT: there is actually a simpler logic for this. Send back "false" for no refresh, otherwise send back the html and save an extra call to get the new html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval("checkTime()", 10000);
    function checkTime(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'checktime.php',
            success: function(refresh){
                if($.trim(refresh) != "false"){
                    $('#myDivID').html(refresh)
                }   
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: You might want something like: `$('#myDivID').load(window.location.href + ' #myDivID')`. Query the current page, grab the element's contents, put them in said element.

Comment: actually sending the html back on first request makes most sense

Comment: I like this approach (the second one) as long as checktime.php is always either "false" or the required HTML. Elegant. However, as per my answer... if the HTML is brief and not dynamic, this could be overkill as the GET itself is still being made and is the heaviest part of it all. If the HTML is light, might as well just throw it in there every X seconds.

Comment: Just want to note: the solution in my above comment is probably the slowest one possible.

Comment: Currently I have this in the <head> of my index.php:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval("checkTime()", 10000);
    function checkTime(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'checktime.php',
            success: function(refresh){
                if($.trim(refresh) != "false"){
                    $('#tv').html(refresh)
                }   
            }
        });
    }

});
</script>`

It's not working though. My 'tv' div contains `<? include tv.php ?>`

Comment: would help if you edited post...and format the code where it is readble...report any errors (if any) in browser console also. looks like your php is sending code as text

Answer (score 1):

We would need to understand exactly what checktime.php is returning. I suggest returning data in JSON format, so that in the future if you want it to have other information (for example... the time!...) it's extensible.

To the second point, you can use jQuery's `.load()` function to just load content into a particular div.

If go the JSON route and your JSON has a member called "refresh" that can be "true" or "false" (notice that I'm using a string here rather than a boolean), your revised function *could* look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    function checkTime(){
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'checktime.php',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.refresh == "true"){
                    $('#myDiv').load('myresource.php');
                }   
            }
        });
    }
    setInterval(function() {checkTime()}, 10000);
});
```

As a suggestion: if the content for that refreshed div isn't enormous and isn't interactive, why not just continually update it and drop the condition? It would greatly simplify the process.

[update] You are also using a string function in setInterval, which uses eval. This is considered a no-no, and you should switch to passing an actual function:

```
setInterval(function() {checkTime()}, 10000);
```

I've updated my code sample accordingly!

Comment: You might want `$('#myDivID').load(window.location.href + ' #myDivID')`

Comment: @Madmartigan I'm not sure I follow. Could you explain in a bit more detail? Why would you want to load the current contents into the current div? There's no net change that way.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what does it mean to refresh a div but you can hide the div and then fade it in:

```
$('#divId').hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: There may not be literally a "refresh a div" function, but I thought the meaning was quite clear. Update the div with changed content.

Answer (score 0):

The part that is causing you the problem is `location.reload(true)`. The page is reloading because you **are** telling it to reload.

But it is quite simple to change data of one `<div>` so it shouldn't cause you much trouble.

To change data of one div you should replace `location.reload(true)` with `$("#target-div").html("New data");`