# Refresh div if PHP page returns true?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery refresh if PHP file echo's 'true'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571447/jquery-refresh-if-php-file-echos-true)

I have the following div on my index:

```
<div id='tv'> <? include 'tv.php' ?> </div>
```

I have a script that changes content in tv.php and returns 'true' at a certain time called checktime.php.

I'm trying to have jQuery in the index header to check the PHP page every 10 seconds and if checktime.php returns 'true' jQuery 'refreshes' the content of the #tv div. This is the code I currently have but it's not working. It seems to check checktime.php but the div doesn't automatically refresh.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval("checkTime()", 10000);
    function checkTime(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'checktime.php',
            success: function(refresh){
                if($.trim(refresh) == "true"){
                    $('#tv').load('tv.php');
                }   
            }
        });
    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you verified the value of 'refresh' (`console.log( refresh)`)? Have you verified that the output of tv.php actually changes between calls?

Comment: Try to implicitly set the `dataType` in your `$.ajax()` call.  Maybe it's not interpreting the return data as text or html.

Comment: Not just a duplicate, but the same user. ;-) Daan, you have no need to ask the same question in a second thread. I agree with Crontab, which is why I suggested using JSON in your other thread. At the very least, try alerting the value of "$.trim(refresh)" to see if it's what you're looking for or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works better for you, you need to adjust SetInterval to work with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'checktime.php',
            success: function(refresh){
                if($.trim(refresh) == "true"){
                    $('#tv').load('tv.php');
                }   
            }
        });
    }, 10000);

});
```